# Running non-matrix stages in parallel to a matrix in Jenkins declarative-pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm converting our enterprise build so that it uses the 'matrix' directive (https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2019/11/22/welcome-to-the-matrix/), but am having trouble optimizing it.  In the pre-matrix world, we have a build step (produces jars), followed by a parallel 'package' step (produces linux and windows distros), essentially followed by a 'system test' phase (execute the windows and linux distros on various JVMs), and we do some 'code quality' inspection in parallel to the package-and-system-test phases.

Much of this seems to lend itself to using 'matrix'.  So, the 'packaging' is clearly a matrix to get windows and linux platforms crafted.  And the 'system test' is another dual-axis matrix of platform and jvm.  I can easily make one matrix follow the other.  So far, so good.

However, I'm stuck with the 'code quality' stuff as an outlier.  Is there a way to run those stages parallel to the matrix runs.  They are independent once the build is created (they do not need to wait for packaging).  They are also time consuming, so running them serially with the two matrix phases makes the build longer.  Jenkins complains if you put a matrix inside a parallel stage.

Any ideas on how to run non-matrix stages in parallel to a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a somewhat IMHO "better" solution:

```yaml
stage {
    matrix {
        axes {
            axis {
                name 'ORIGAXIS'
                values 'ALPHA','BETA','BAR','BAZ'
            }
        }
        stages {
           stage ("alpha") {
               when { expression { env.ORIGAXIS == "ALPHA" } }
               steps {
                   alpha()
               }           
           stage ("beta") {
               when { expression { env.ORIGAXIS == "BETA" } }
               steps {
                   beta()
               }
           }
           stage ("Tests") {
               when { allOf
                   expression { env.ORIGAXIS != "ALPHA" }
                   expression { env.ORIGAXIS != "BETA" }
               }
               stages {
                   stage("First") {
                      originalFirst( ...)
                    }
                   stage("Second") {
                      originalSecond(...)
                   }
                }
            }
     }
}
```

Of course, the final layout is not perfect. But, it works, is not that much cumbersome and still easily maintainable.

Comment: This looks interesting.  I have not tried it, but does it not create a cartesian where you have vertical matrix for alpha/beta/bar/baz and in each of those there is a alpha/beta/bar/baz stage.  Of course, the bar stage only executes in the bar matrix line, etc, so it does perform correctly and it is less code.  But as you say, the display is likely goofy.

Comment: The display is goofy... But pure declarative pipeline so you gey the davantage of the syntax validation (Meaning better UX too). But anyway, I notice afterwards I cannot use matrix in my case: the matrix axes cannot be variable.

Comment: .. a tangent ...   Matrix axis cannot be variable, but you can specify all of the possible ones, then conditionally turn off the ones you don't want - pseudo variable

Answer (score 1):

I have a work-around to my own question.

According to the documentation (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-matrix) what I am looking for is not possible.  "Each cell in a matrix can include one or more stages to be run sequentially using the configuration for that cell. Note that a stage must have one and only one of steps, stages, parallel, or matrix. It is not possible to nest a parallel or matrix block within a stage directive if that stage directive is nested within a parallel or matrix block itself."

But.... you can cheat.   I was able to turn the matrix into a generic dispatch queue. i.e. each combination invokes N stages - for me, 2 and I call them "prepare" and "execute".  I pass an additional "matrixtype" argument in.  The matrixtype gets 1 value for the matrix itself, as well as additional values for each line of the non-matrix.  I then use the matrix 'excludes' to insure that the non-matrix lines execute only once.  Effectively, this folds the non matrix into the matrix differentiated by matrix type.

```
Original (parallel-stages in series with a subsequent matrix)
    stage {
        parallel {
           stage("alpha") {
                alpha(..)
           }
           stage("beta") {
               beta(..)
           }
           // etc
       }
    }
    stage {
        matrix {
            axes {
                axis {
                    name 'ORIGAXIS'
                    values 'FOO','BAR','BAZ'
                }
            }
            stages {
               stage("First") {
                  originalFirst( ...)
               }
               stage("Second") {
                  originalSecond(...)
               }
            }
         }
      }

Replacement (parallel folded into matrix)
    stage {
        matrix {
            axes {
                axis {
                    name 'MATRIXTYPE
                    values 'ORIGINAL', 'ALPHA', 'BETA'
                axis {
                    name 'ORIGAXIS'
                    values 'FOO','BAR','BAZ'
                }
                excludes {
                    // Execute Alpha and Beta only once (during 'FOO')
                    exclude {
                        axis {
                            name 'MATRIXTYPE'
                            values 'ALPHA', 'BETA'
                        }
                        axis {
                            name 'ORIGAXIS'
                            values 'BAR','BAZ'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            stages {
               stage("First") {
                  dispatchFirst( "${MATRIXTYPE}", ...)
               }
               stage("Second") {
                  dispatchSecond( "${MATRIXTYPE}", ...)
               }
            }
         }
      }
```

The dispatchFirst(..) and dispatchSecond(..) are then simple dispatch methods in the shared lib that examine matrixtype, and invoke originalFirst(..), originalSecond(..), alpha(..), beta(..) or a no-op as appropriate.   It's slightly clumsy, and amounts to shoehorning the parallel stages into the matrix, but it works.  And, you get the benefit of parallelization (build speed-optimization)

Hopefully in the future, there will be something more elegant.

---

Updated (2022-09-22):  What the 'replacement' does is brute-force the heck out of it.  It creates a matrix with 9 permutations:
**ORIGINAL-FOO**, **ORIGINAL-BAR**, **ORIGINAL-BAZ**, **ALPHA-FOO**, ALPHA-BAR, ALPHA-BAZ, **BETA-FOO**, BETA-BAR, BETA-BAZ.   The exclude then gets rid of ALPHA-BAR, ALPHA-BAZ, BETA-BAR, BETA-BAZ, leaving 5 executable elements (emphazied above) in the matrix.   For each of the 5 elements, the matrix will call the "dispatchFirst" then "dispatchSecond" method, passing the matrix variables over to it.

You then implement dispatchFirst such that:
if matrixType == ALPHA, invoke alpha() [only gets called once]
if matrixType == BETA, invoke beta()  [only gets called once]
otherwise, invoke originalFirst(..) using FOO/BAR/BAZ as passed in

And dispatchSecond only operates if matrixType=ORIGINAL, and it calls originalSecond(..) using FOO/BAR/BAZ as passed in.

Comment: Can I get you to map out your alpha/beta, and foo/bar/baz into meaningful stages of work? I can follow your original question but this abstraction in renaming has made me lose the plot. I guess I understand why because this is an adaptation of the naming scheme the other answerer presented, but it is too difficult to follow the exact evolution thereof and the relevant reasoning involved. My understanding of the question is you want your code quality to run in parallel with those two other matrix blocks, (those two matrix blocks themselves could be sequential?)

Comment: and I am able to gather that First is the Build, and Second is going to dispatch into either package & system test OR code quality. But I cannot see how you're planning to fit the dependency of how system test has to happen after packages are built, as an example, since you are no longer able to nest any further matrix into the Second stage.

Comment: The way that I could envision this on my first reading of this was you basically take all the dimensions that exist (in your example, this might be 3 axes, although I'm not clear on it: platform, jvms, code quality tools), and make a master full dimensional matrix out of it. Say you have 3 plats (Windows, Ubuntu, RHEL), 5 JVM versions, and 2 code tools, this would be a matrix of 3*5*2 = 30 cells.

Comment: It is way easier to reason about once we plot it out... although a 3D spreadsheet is tricky to think about, but we do whatever is easiest and maybe add a dummy value to plats and JVM axes called `codequal` (now we're up to 40 cells) and cull out the resultant cells that don't make sense using `exclude`, so only the 2 cells where plat=codequal AND JVM=codequal are going to be running the codequal ones, and then all the rest of the 15 cells for plat x JVM can all run as usual.  And they would all go in parallel, which is def what we want.